# Создание класса с объектом ООП

Tags: java, ооп

Начал изучать ООП с Java, на первом практическом задании столкнулся с проблемой, которую пока не могу решить. Есть идея и понимание того, как в теории надо это сделать - но реализовать на практике не получается.

Код задания:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Things {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String characterString;
        Scanner reader =  new Scanner(System.in);        
        PrintingClass printer = new PrintingClass();

        System.out.print("Type in the character string for printing: ");
        characterString = reader.nextLine();
        printer.Print(characterString);
    }
}

//  Write the missing class here
//  Class is written in the text box below.
```

Нужно написать новый class, который позволит сделать следующий вывод:

> Type in the character string for printing: Matt Jackson is here
>
> Matt Jackson is here

Понимаю, что нужно создать класс

```
public class printingClass
```

И внутри него должен быть объект

```
printer
```

Взаимодействие с которым должно как-то вызывать функцию

```
System.out.print
```

Которая содержит введенный пользователем текст.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Судя по всему , в классе PrintingClass нужно создать метод Print и должно получится что-то похожее на это                                                                                                                            public class PrintingClass{
 public void Print(String str){
  System.out.println(str);
 }
}

Comment: Спасибо! Это действительно то, что мне было нужно!

Answer (score 1):

> И внутри него должен быть объект printer

Это не совсем корректная формулировка. Вас просят описать новый класс, который в себе содержит определенный метод.

---

Давай разберем исходный код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Things {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String characterString; // Объявляем переменную characterString типа String  
        Scanner reader =  new Scanner(System.in); // Создаем объект, который позволит считать строку, введенную в консоли   
        PrintingClass printer = new PrintingClass(); // Создаем объект нашего класса (используется дефолтный конструктор без параметров)

        System.out.print("Type in the character string for printing: "); // Выводим строку в консоль
        characterString = reader.nextLine(); // Считываем строку из консоли 
        printer.Print(characterString); // Выводим значение переменной characterString  на консоль 
    }
}
```

---

Решение, к примеру, может быть таким:

```
public class PrintingClass { // описываем структуру класса 

    public void Print(String str) { // описание нашего метода 
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

Или такой вариант:

```
public class PrintingClass {

    public PrintingClass() {
    }

    public void Print(String str) {
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

По факту оба решения выше одинаковы. Прошу заметить, если вы явно не определяете ни один конструктор, то язык за вас создаст конструктор по-умолчанию (без параметров). Если же вы определили хотя бы один конструктор, то конструктор по умолчанию создан не будет.

---

В вашем примере метод у класса PrintingClass начинается с большой буквы, так именовать в языке не принято. Выдержка из конвенции о наименовании на языке Java:

> Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
>   lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.

Вольный перевод:
Методы описывают действие. Название начинается со строчной первой буквы, если в имени несколько слов, каждое следующее слово пишется с заглавной буквы слитно.

Подробнее о правилах наименования можете почитать здесь:
[Naming Conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/codeconventions-135099.html).

---

Удачи в изучении языка!